# foreach loop not working in a do while loop

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have a small bit of code that I have had to run per year level and I wanted to make it run in a do while loop so that there isn't as much code. The idea is that the code will save a var with a string and int 
ie.. yr1 yr2 yr3 and so on.
The main issue is that it works if I just run it in a normal for loop so i can't understand why it wont work.

```
$searchbase1 = 'OU=test 1,OU=USR,DC=contoso,DC=local'
$searchbase2 = 'OU=test 2,OU=USR,DC=contoso,DC=local'
$searchbase3 = 'OU=test 3,OU=USR,DC=contoso,DC=local'
$searchbase4 = 'OU=test 4,OU=USR,DC=contoso,DC=local'
$searchbase5 = 'OU=test 5,OU=USR,DC=contoso,DC=local'
$searchbase6 = 'OU=test 6,OU=USR,DC=contoso,DC=local'
$searchbaser = 'OU=test r,OU=USR,DC=contoso,DC=local'
$searchbases = 'OU=del,OU=USR,DC=contoso,DC=local'

$yr1 = Get-ADUser -Filter * -searchbase $searchbaser -Properties *
$yr2 = Get-ADUser -Filter * -searchbase $searchbase1 -Properties * 
$yr3 = Get-ADUser -Filter * -searchbase $searchbase2 -Properties * 
$yr4 = Get-ADUser -Filter * -searchbase $searchbase3 -Properties * 
$yr5 = Get-ADUser -Filter * -searchbase $searchbase4 -Properties * 
$yr6 = Get-ADUser -Filter * -searchbase $searchbase5 -Properties * 
$yr7 = Get-ADUser -Filter * -searchbase $searchbase6 -Properties * 
$yr8 = Get-ADUser -Filter * -searchbase $searchbases -Properties * 

$elem=0
do
{
    $elem+=1
    $yr='test'+'$elem'
    ForEach ($ADUser in $yr)  
    {
        $homeDirectory = "\\dc1\database\$($ADUser.sAMAccountname)" 
        $homeDrive = "H"

        Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUser.sAMAccountname -Replace @{HomeDirectory=$homeDirectory} 
        Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUser.sAMAccountname -Replace @{HomeDrive=$homeDrive} 
        Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUser.sAMAccountname –scriptPath “Student.bat”  
        if ($homeDirectory){}else{mkdir $homeDirectory}
    }
}
while($elem -le 8)
```

Comment: `$yr` is everytime assigning test + element number. So why you need `foreach` then? Anyways, its gonna iterate one time. But your do while will iterate till`-le 8`

Comment: Can you describe what doesn't work? Does it throw an exception? What do you expect vs what actually happens.

Comment: this is the error i get: Set-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null.

The whole idea is that all the students in the OU's will get their home directory assigned in AD so that when the user logs into the computer they are able to save to the SMB file share. it also adds the studet.bat file to the AD user so that the student setup file will run when they login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rewritten your script to a way I find more easy personally.

```
$searchAreas = @{
    searchbase1 = 'OU=test 1,OU=USR,DC=contoso,DC=local'
    searchbase2 = 'OU=test 2,OU=USR,DC=contoso,DC=local'
    searchbase3 = 'OU=test 3,OU=USR,DC=contoso,DC=local'
    searchbase4 = 'OU=test 4,OU=USR,DC=contoso,DC=local'
    searchbase5 = 'OU=test 5,OU=USR,DC=contoso,DC=local'
    searchbase6 = 'OU=test 6,OU=USR,DC=contoso,DC=local'
    searchbaser = 'OU=test r,OU=USR,DC=contoso,DC=local'
    searchbases = 'OU=del,OU=USR,DC=contoso,DC=local'
}

foreach($area in $searchAreas.Values){
    $yr = Get-ADUser -Filter * -searchbase $area -Properties *
    foreach($ADUser in $yr){
        $homeDirectory = "\\dc1\database\$($ADUser.sAMAccountname)" 
        $homeDrive = "H"

        try{
            Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUser.SamAccountName -Replace @{HomeDirectory=$homeDirectory} 
        }catch{
            Write-Host "Failed to set user because $($_.Exception.Message)" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
        Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUser.SamAccountName -Replace @{HomeDrive=$homeDrive} 
        Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUser.SamAccountName –scriptPath “Student.bat”  
        if($homeDirectory){

        }else{
            mkdir $homeDirectory
        }
    }
}
```

Also check the try catch methods around Set-ADUser. I strongly advise to always add try catch to all your calls (so you will have to add them to all other Set-ADUser cmdlets and to mkdir etc.

Hope this helps

Comment: Note that instead of a hashtable for the values, you could also create an array! :)

Answer (score 0):

User Powershell_ISE. If you save the script and add a breakpoint (F9) at Set-ADUser. The script will break. Now select the $ADUser.sAMAccountname and press (F8). You will see the value of the parameter. Now you will understand more easily why it is not working.

It must have something to do with the fact that you set 'test' + '$elem'. Also, single quotes around the variable will make it a string instead of variable. So check this output:

```
$yr='test'+'$elem'
$yr
```

Result is:

> test$elem

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks,
I can see what you mean now.
looks like I will need to keep it just in for loops as I have tried without quotes:
The assignment expression is not valid. The input to an assignment operator must be an object that is able to accept assignments, such as a variable or a property